# iOS 6 pushing viewcontrollers in a modally presented viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

In my app i would like to create a tutorial to show how to use the app.

For that i presented a viewcontroller using `navcontroller.presentViewController` and it has a form appearance. I would like to change the `viewcontroller` to an other but i don't know how to.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Zoli

EDIT: What i want to achieve

i'm on the mainViewController

With `navcontroller.presentViewController` I present the `welcomeScreenViewController1`
Then i want to move from `welcomeScreenViewController1` to `welcomeScreenViewController2` without having to dismiss `welcomeScreenViewController1` first. The best would be if in that modal view, i could push `welcomeScreenViewController2` onto `welcomeScreenViewController1`.

I hope that helps

Comment: create new controller object and present that instead of earlier

Comment: sorry but your question is not that descriptive. can you please give little more details about the same

Comment: if you want a stack of view controllers, use the navigation controller and push onto that stack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your modal screen needs to be a navigation controller. So you need to do :

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeScreenViewController1];    
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, you should be able to push your welcomeViewController2 in your navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of presenting a view, present a navigation controller.

Comment: I tried that too, i get this error: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target